# Short/simplify regex with or condtion

Tags: regex

I have written the following regEx to check for the below conditions

- Combination of at-least one lowerCase a-z with Uppercase A-Z
- Combination of at-least one lowerCase a-z with a digit 0-9
- Combination of at-least one UpperCase A-Z with a digit 0-9

```
((?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]))|((?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9]))|((?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9]))
```

valid inputs are:-

- aA
- a1
- A1

Is there any way to short/simplify this regex?

Comment: Can you give examples of valid/invalid inputs? Are non-alphanumerical characters allowed?

Comment: i added the valid input examples.

Comment: Can you also add examples of invalid input, and answer the question whether non-alphabetical characters are allowed?

Comment: aa,ZZ,11 are the invalid examples

Comment: And... are non-alphabetical characters allowed? You seem to avoid this question? So `"a+1"`, `"Z-=3"`,`"(aaaaZZZZ)"`... are they allowed?

Comment: @trincot No, non-alphabetical chars are not allowed. sorry i missed the part when i replied.

Comment: Could you update your question to clarify that only alphanumerical characters are allowed? I have updated my answer. Could you check?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the rules could be rephrased like:

- Input must consist of only alphanumerical characters
- Reject any input that only consists of digits
- Reject any input that only consists of lowercase letters
- Reject any input that only consists of uppercase letters

Your regular expression does not check for the start/end of the input, nor does it verify that all characters are alphanumerical (`.*` is too broad), so it would accept inputs that are invalid.

You could do it like this:

[`^(?!\d*$|[A-Z]*$|[a-z]*$)[a-zA-Z\d]*$`](https://regex101.com/r/YA0kbr/1)

Answer (score 0):

Would `([a-z]+[A-Z])|(([a-z]+|[A-Z]+)[0-9])` be what you're looking for?

Comment: The input does not necessarily have to start with a letter.